# Preg replace callback validation

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I need to re-write some old code that I found on a library.

```
    $text = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e",
                         "'\\1'.strtolower('\\2').'\\3'", $text);

    $text = preg_replace("/<br[ \/]*>\s*/","\n",$text);
    $text = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n",
                         $text);
```

And for the first one I have tried like this:

```
 $text = preg_replace_callback(
   "/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/",
   function($subs) {
       return strtolower($subs[0]);
   },
   $text);
```

I'm a bit confused b/c I don't understand this part: `"'\\1'.strtolower('\\2').'\\3'"` so I'm not sure what should I replace it with.

As far as I understand the first line looks for tags, and makes them lowercase in case I have data like

```
<B>FOO</B>
```

Can you guys help me out here with a clarification, and If my code is done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$subs` is an array that contains the whole value in the first item and captured texts in the subsequent items. So, Group 1 is in `$subs[1]`, Group 2 value is in `$subs[2]`, etc. The `$subs[0]` contains the whole match value, and you applied `strtolower` to it, but the original code left the Group 3 value (captured with `([^>]*>)` that may also contain uppercase letters) intact.

Use

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("~(</?)(\w+)([^>]*>)~", function($subs) {
    return $subs[1] . strtolower($subs[2]) . $subs[3]; 
 }, $text);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/1rd6Zn).